# Delete all data in all tables older than period using date column

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I have a set of tables, which all have a date column (timestamp without time zone) equal to time inserted.

How would I go about deleting all data in all tables older than 24 hours using the date column, and preferably without explicitly deleting each table using a model?

Here's how I'm deleting everything from all tables now, but it feels somewhat hacky when adding tests for date.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@host:port/database')
meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=engine)

for table in reversed(meta.sorted_tables):
    engine.execute(table.delete())
```

Comment: are you deleting all the rows in the table?  cannot tell from code.  if so, you could you use `truncate` instead of `delete` -  in pg, _much_ faster

Comment: Yes, it'll delete everything in each table retrieved using sqlalchemy.MetaData().reflect(). You're right about truncate if you want to delete the whole table, but that's not what I want and it seems to be out of the scope of my question.

Comment: that's cool.  know pg, but did not understand you question at all.  lots of luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following should do it:

```
import datetime
too_old = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
for table in reversed(meta.sorted_tables):
    engine.execute(table.delete().where(table.c.timestampinserted <= too_old))
```

Note that you might have issues in case you have `foreign key constraints`. Also `truncate` does not work if the table is referenced by a `foreign key constraint`.

Comment: While there was some errors with your code (I gave it a edit), the idea was correct and it's working just fine, thanks!

Comment: @TimSæterøy Your suggested edit has been rejected by 3 reviewers (can't really blame them, the current review system has close to no context). I've redone your edit on the answer. If anything, try editing again or @ me.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Oh, ok. I haven't heard of any problems with the review system, but thanks anyway. The accepted answer should atleast be of correct syntax :)

Comment: @TimSæterøy Exactly why I did the update manually. `:P` Though I'm not very much of a Meta guy, I should bring this up as an improvement suggestion on Meta.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yeah, I think you should if there's anything flawed with the review system. Sure, it's a little odd for me as the questioner to edit an answers contents, but this was pretty harmless and shouldn't be rejected.

Comment: @TimSæterøy Ok, made my first actual post on Meta [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175758/186879).